# How to expand absolutely positioned child element to fullscreen width?

Tags: html, css, frontend, padding, margin

I have horizontal bar having some margin from left and right.
I want to add overlay behind the bar and want to stretch to full-screen width (just like modal dialog overlay) but top position of overlay should be same as top position of bar as well bottom position of overlay should same as bottom position of bar.
However due to spacing from left and right I cannot stretch it to full-screen width. So I tried adding negative left/right position equal to left/right margin value to make it fullscreen.
However this solution not proper seems to be proper, because margin of left/right can be of any value in future and is not hardcoded.
Is there any ideal generic solution for it.

Following is the code snippet:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px; --> Margins can be any value not just hardcoded
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.bar {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
.overlay {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  background: purple;
  left: -50px; --> Set negative position to stretch it to fullscreen but not seems to be proper solution as margin can be of any value
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this

```
<div class="parent"> 
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div> 
 </div>
```

Add these styles

```
body {
    margin:0;
}

.parent { 
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px; 
}

.bar { height: 50px; background: blue; }
  
.overlay { 
    z-index: -1; 
    position: absolute; 
    background: purple; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;    
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
}
```

Comment: hi @Dinesh Rout, Actually overlay should be only wider to stretch to fullscreen, and its top position should be same as top position of bar and same for bottom position and if my bar is somewhere in middle or bottom position of page overlay top/bottom position should be insync with it.

Comment: fixed it https://codepen.io/DineshRout/pen/XWMjXya?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

You could move your `overlay` out of the parent element, and remove all those margins.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50px; 
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.bar {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
.overlay {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  background: purple;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @prettyInPink, this is not working because top position of overlay should be same as top position of bar, only thing is that left and right should stretch out to fullscreen.

Comment: So the overlay should have the same height as the bar? Updated example.

Comment: Yes, should have same height as the bar as well as top position should always be same as bar.

Comment: Can you check my updated answer. With the parent set to ```relative``` the absolute positioned element, will not overflow this. Since the parent does not have any height set and adapts to the height of the inner child ```.bar```,  the overlay will start and end at the top and bottom of ```.bar```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed` for **.overlay**. And set left and right 0.  For more about [fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed)

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
.parent {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.bar {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
.overlay {
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  background: purple;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @PrakashM, thanks for the solution, but however this is not working in all cases, if my bar is some where at bottom of my page then overlay will still remain at top due to top: 0 and fixed position, its top position should remain in sync with top position of bar, only thing is that left and right should be stretch to fullscreen, Thats why I have given postion absolute but due to this left/right position is constrained due to margin of left and right.